# how create multiple parsing with axios

Tags: javascript

How to create a request queue? if you build sequential queries, then they are called simultaneously

```
const s1 = async () => {
axios(url_benzinga)
      .then(response => {
        var html = response.data;
       var $ = cheerio.load(html)

const s2 = async () => {
axios(url_benzinga)
      .then(response => {
        var html = response.data;
       var $ = cheerio.load(html)
```

**I can not understand how to do it right**

https://ibb.co/ngPr45p

https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/371

It would look something like:

```
axios.get('http://google.com')
  .then((res) => {
    // do something with Google res

    return axios.get('http://apple.com');
  })
  .then((res) => {
    // do something with Apple res
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle err
  });
Alternatively you can send both requests simultaneously and handle responses at the same time:

axios.all([
    axios.get('http://google.com'),
    axios.get('http://apple.com')
  ])
  .then(axios.spread((googleRes, appleRes) => {
    // do something with both responses
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

i think this is not the right solution

```js
axios.get('api')
.then(res => {
  // first save this api response anywhere. then after that particular action call next api otherwise i think it will be complex or sometime axios . then return an error so should also aware from such error 
})
.catch(err => console.log(err.message))
```

Comment: does not help, it works simultaneously  https://ibb.co/6PP2fv4

Comment: after 1 axios goes puppeteer then owes 2 axios after puppeteer

Answer (score 0):

It is easy with `async/await` syntax.

Example, you have 2 requests like:

```
const s1 = async () => {
  return axios.get('http://google.com');
}

const s2 = async () => {
  return axios.get('http://apple.com');
}
```

Now, if you want to take request in sequential

```
// sequential queries,
const res1 = await s1();
const res2 = await s2();

// do something with both responses
```

and, request in parallel

```
const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
  s1(),
  s2(),
]);
// do something with both responses
```

Comment: const res1 = await s1();
const res2 = await s2(); Does not help

Comment: puppeteer runs sequentially, but axios doesn't

Comment: https://www.ninjadevcorner.com/2019/10/build-an-asynchronous-web-scraping-tool-with-node-js-and-cheerio-js.html?m=1

Comment: I think need to do it like this